# Time Out для post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Как сделать time-out для нажатия кнопки отправки формы методом POST. Есть простая форма:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="Введите данные">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Как сделать перерыв между обработкой формы, т.е. можно нажать только 1 раз в 15 минут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отправке формы пишем в базу время time.php.

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE dbName.table SET `lastAction` = '$time' WHERE `dbName`.`id_user` = $idUser");
```

далее в отдельном скрипте check.php нужна функция, которая будет возвращать true, если прошло более 15 минут

```
function checkingTheTime($idUsers)
{
 mysqly_query($link, SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=$idUsers && `online` > NOW() -  INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
if(mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0){
return true;
}
return false;
}
$enableSending = function checkingTheTime($idUsers);
echo $enableSending;
```

Это что касательно php. далее на странице нужен js, который будет делать ajax и менять класс у кнопки (например hidden/visible).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//при нажатию на кнопку, #btn
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $('#btn').addClass('hidden');
    $.ajax({
        url: "time.php"
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php"
    })
        .done(function (Data) {
            // Делаем обработку данных returnedData
            if (Data == true) {
                $('#btn').removeClass('hidden');
            }
        });
  });
 });
```

По поводу JS могу ошибаться, но в целом идея я думаю понятна.